# Sylow P-Subgroups of Normal Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Just as a note, please don't give me the proof, I feel like I'm close and am just looking for a point in the right direction.

I am trying to prove that if $G$ is a finite group with $|G|$ = $p^nm$, and $N \lhd G$, such that $p||N|$, and $P \lt G$ is a sylow p-subgroup then $P \cap N$ is also a sylow p-subgroup of $N$.

I have so far that there is a sylow p-subgroup in N because $p||N|$, and now I am trying to use Sylow's 2nd Theorem along with the fact that $N \lhd G$ and that all sylow subgroups are conjugate to each other.

My proof so far is as follows:
$P_N \lt N \lhd G \Rightarrow P_N \lt G$ so $P_N$ is also a slyow p subgroup of G,
$\Rightarrow g(P_N)g^{-1} = P$ by the second sylow theorem $\Rightarrow P\cap N = P_N$

$\therefore P \cap N$ is a sylow p-subgroup $\blacksquare$

I'm not sure where the flaw in my reasoning is, but I don't use the fact that $N$ is normal at all, which is my first hint that I'm wrong, so my idea is to use the second theorem again somehow between finding $P_N$ in $N$ and claiming that $P_N \lt G$. Any advice is greatly appreciated, thank you.

I apologize for confusion, I am not good at English lol, but I think I fixed my problems

Comment: The result is false. Just take an abelian group $G$ of order $p^2$, and let $N$ have order $p$. Then $P=G$, and $G\cap N=N$ is not a $p$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: You write "I know there is a Sylow $p$-subgroup contained in $N$ because $p||N|$. That's false. You know that $N$ has $p$-Sylow subgroups **of $N$**, but they need not be Sylow subgroups of $G$ unless you also know that $p^n$ divides $|N|$. If $p^n$ divides $|N|$, then any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, and in fact every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ will be contained in $N$.

Comment: @ThePhoenix: That's as maybe, but that is not what is written. Note in particular that is says "$P\cap N$ is **also** a Sylow $p$-subgroup". The "also" is a problem.

Comment: You can find abelian groups with $|G|=p^2m$ such that $|N|=p$, so the intersection $|P\cap N|\le p<p^2$. How can it be p-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: I apologize! I mistyped!! @ArturoMagidin

Comment: What you've added just reinforces my interpretation, which means what you are trying to prove is false. Are you trying to prove that $N\cap P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup **of $N$**?

Comment: @ThePhoenix you are correct which is why I specifically said I don't want an answer just a tip. Does this change the validity of my proof at all?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes I mistyped again :/

Comment: Ok, now that is fixed. You really need to keep separate being a Sylow $p$-subgroup *of $G$* and *of $N$*. So you have to stop just saying "Sylow $p$-subgroup", and always add **of whom**. So "I know there is a Sylow $p$-subgroup in $N$" is imprecise at best. What you mean is "I know that $N$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup of itself". Etc.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes I apologize, sometimes I think faster than I speak or type.

Comment: You are asserting that $P_N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. That is not necessarily true, unless $p^n$ divides $|N|$. All you know about $P_N$ is that it is a $p$-subgroup of $G$. So you need to use the First Sylow Theorem to find a Sylow $p$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$ such that $P_N\leq Q$. Then you can use Sylow's Second Theorem to conjugate $Q$ into $P$. Moreover, the Second Theorem doesn't tell you that $gP_Ng^{-1}=P$; it tells you that if $Q$ is any other Sylow $p$-subgroup *of $G$* then there exists $g\in G$ such that $gQg^{-1}=P$. Now you need to see what happens to $gP_Ng^{-1}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ok! I will try that, thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

> $P_N \lt N \lhd G \Rightarrow P_N \lt G$ so $P_N$ is also a slyow p subgroup of G,

Let $G=Z_{12}, P_N=N=\{0, 6\}, $, but $P_N$ is not Sylow p-subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $PN/N \cong P/(P \cap N)$ and consider the power of $p$ that divides the order of each group.